# reader writer state monad - how to run this scala code

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

Tony Morris gave a talk with this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/2360532).

He's using ReaderWriterState monad to provide controlled read/write access to an implicit context. That makes sense.

How do I use the code? I would like to see an example "main" program that uses this monad.

Comment: There's an example linked from the comments on that gist: https://gist.github.com/2364137

Comment: To understand how using this Monad, translate the for (...) yield {} of the example in terms of flatMap and map and look how implicit are defined to implement Monoid Trait ( id and op method ) and Functor Trait ( fmap )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Scalaz 7](https://gist.github.com/2364137) now provides this monad, and the following is a complete working example, translated with minor revisions from [the example by Michael Pilquist](https://gist.github.com/2364137) that's linked in the comments above.

```
package scalaz.example

import scalaz._, Scalaz._


object RWSExample extends App {
  case class Config(port: Int)

  def log[R, S](msg: String): ReaderWriterState[R, List[String], S, Unit] =
    ReaderWriterStateT {
      case (r, s) => (msg.format(r, s) :: Nil, (), s).point[Id]
    }

  def invokeService: ReaderWriterState[Config, List[String], Int, Int] =
    ReaderWriterStateT {
      case (cfg, invocationCount) => (
        List("Invoking service with port " + cfg.port),
        scala.util.Random.nextInt(100),
        invocationCount + 1).point[Id]
    }

  val program: RWS[Config, List[String], Int, Int] = for {
    _ <- log("Start - r: %s, s: %s")
    res <- invokeService
    _ <- log("Between - r: %s, s: %s")
    _ <- invokeService
    _ <- log("Done - r: %s, s: %s")
  } yield res

  val (logMessages, result, invocationCount) = program run (Config(443), 0)
  println("Result: " + result)
  println("Service invocations: " + invocationCount)
  println("Log: %n%s".format(logMessages.mkString("\t", "%n\t".format(), "")))
}
```

This is tested against Scalaz 7.2.18, which is [easily available](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.12/7.2.18) from Maven's Central Repository as a Maven or SBT dependency.

Comment: I am failing to see where the `Random.nextInt` fits into anything there... it doesn't come back into the `invocationCount`, so is there a reason it's not just `Unit` ? or `0` ?

Comment: With Scala 7.2, the code above needs to be modified. Replace `Identity` with `Id`.  This line no longer compiles: `val Need(logMessages, result, invocationCount) = program run (Config(443), 0)`, but I don't know enough Scala or Scalaz to explain why.

Comment: // below line worked for me
```val (logMessages, result, invocationCount)  = program run (Config(443), 0)```